# Dot selector based on algo's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, frontend

We're currently using ReactJS and MaterialUI for our front end, there's a specific component that we're struggling with and we're not sure what's the best way to do it. If it should be a slider: https://material-ui.com/components/slider/ or stepper https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/ or a line with simple selectable dots. It's also hard to know where to look...

Here is a exemple, basically we have a algorithm working in the back end that will select one of the four exclusion dots on a vertical line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario vertical stepper would be the best choice.
Link : https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

You can modify or remove the next and back button as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I believe this is the best option.